# Custom dimens.xml for mdpi devices - how it can be done?

Tags: android, layout, screen

My application have layout, which looks perfect at all devices, except devices with mdpi screen destiny. Activity just doesn't fit to screen on mdpi devices.

So I want to create special dimens.xml for these type of devices.
I created "values-mdpi" folder next to my "values" folder, created new dimens.xml into it and set dimens values for mdpi devices.

res/values/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="logo_block_height">100dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="logo_block_height">50dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

And ImageView that uses that dimen:

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_block_height"
        android:id="@+id/font_logo" android:adjustViewBounds="false" android:src="@drawable/bg_font_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

The problem is that values now applied for all devices, not only for mdpi, but for hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi too.

I want it to work like that:

- If device screen destiny is mdpi or lower - use values from values-mdpi folder
- If device screen destiny is MORE than mdpi - use default "values" folder.

How it can be done?

Comment: I would suggest that you fix your problem in some other way. Using density qualifiers (e.g., `-mdpi`) for anything other than drawables is unlikely to give you what you want.

Comment: You  must put a dimens.xml in your `values` folder, too. With the default values.

Comment: @DerGolem i have it in my "values" folder, of course.

Comment: @CommonsWare so what way You suggest? I will be happy to any method

Comment: It works, for me. But I added all the density folders. So, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, ....

Comment: @DerGolem other folders You created is empty? Or You put dimens.xml with default values in every folder?

Comment: No... I put the proper values for each density. Since these are dimensions, I want them to vary a little for each density.

Comment: @udenfox Please provide a reproducing example code. When you specify **dip** values in dimens.xml, there should be no difference among densities of course.

Comment: @hata I added some code.

Comment: @udenfox probably Commonsware means that it's more typical to use _another resource qualifier_ like **smallest width** e.g. `values-sw320dp`

Comment: @ataulm That qualifier will work same it that situation, as i understand it. Values from that folder will apply for every device which have "smaller-width" value more than 320dp. I need to set dimens for devices with screen destiny **smaller** than mdpi (160dpi)

Comment: I'm not saying it _won't_ work the same. It's likely that you're mis-using them though; `dp` units indicate _density independent pixels_, that is, you shouldn't be swapping them based on the device's screen density. I suppose you're testing on screens with a different physical size, and these happen to be MDPI.

Comment: @ataulm that's right. Thank You for noticing that. I will edit my own answer soon. Or You can post Your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I came up with only one solution for that without creating values folder for each screen density.

When at least one "values" folder with destiny qualifiers created android selects the most suitable folder for device screen destiny.
This is the reason why it selects "values-mdpi" for everything that bigger or smaller than mdpi.

Also, like [ataulm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115430/custom-dimens-xml-for-mdpi-devices-how-it-can-be-done#comment44624309_28115430) said, there are no sense use screen density qualifiers in that situations. I can have phone with 340x480 with 160dpi where content doesn't fit and Tablet with 1280x800 with 160dpi where there is too much free space.

I solved that by creating Values folder with minimal-height qualifiers.
I have folder "values-h480dp" with values for every device with minimum 480 dp availible height and put default values in it. In default "values" folder i put values for devices with small screen.

Now it works like I need:

- If device have availible height more than 480dp - it uses values from "values-h480dp" folder.
- If device have availible height less than 480dp - it uses values from "values" folder.

I sorry for my bad English and hope that this has helped someone.